# Expand and Collapase in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create a Layout that have the feature of expand and collapse .Expand should be like that at a time only one row can be expanded ,if user clicks on other first should be closed by itself.In each row i have to show different layout design .

[image: How it will look like]

Please help me in this ,i have searched but i am not getting i how could i create this functionality .Please take this as a reference how it will be like .Please suggest me the best approach to get this

Comment: Why don't you use `ExpandableListView` ?

Comment: Layout for each header will be different so how can we do this ExpandableListView

Comment: If your all data is different for all Header then you can use Sliding Up and Sliding down animation for that.

Comment: You can give simple `if and else` condition accordingly.

Comment: different layout design means just change background color or want to inflate separate layout?

Comment: inflating different layout

Comment: See my Answer blow hope that may help you...

Comment: @PoojaDubey do you find the solution for your question? I have same requirement as yours. The answer you have accepted is not executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented some code as the answer suggested by @Super User. So from that i think you will sure get your solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:accordion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.sentaca.android.accordion"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Offline Booking Request"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <com.sentaca.android.accordion.widget.AccordionView
        android:id="@+id/accordion_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        accordion:header_layout_fold_button_id="@id/foldButton"
        accordion:header_layout_id="@layout/accordion_header"
        accordion:header_layout_label_id="@id/foldText"
        accordion:section_bottom="@layout/accordion_footer"
        accordion:section_container="@layout/accordion_section"
        accordion:section_container_parent="@id/section_content"
        accordion:section_headers="@array/accordion_sections"
        accordion:section_visibility="@array/accordion_visibility"
        android:background="#fff5f5f5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please specify offline car details if you need any cars of travels"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="45dp"
                android:text="Plase click the checkbox to send the details"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <include layout="@layout/radio" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/example_get_by_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 4" />
    </com.sentaca.android.accordion.widget.AccordionView>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Review" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Confirm" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now just remember one thing whenever you want to add layout items then add item in Linear Layout and make different layout for different sections and after that include that layout in your Linear layout. I have tried for one section named radio.xml file which is included in Linear Layout above.

***radio.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Domestic"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="InterNational"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />
</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Pick Up Location"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="DropLocation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Car Type"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Remarks"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `lib` [Accordion-View](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view) screenshot is :
[image]

Comment: how could i use this i am not getting that .i have to use this inside a fragment >>

Comment: see this https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view/blob/master/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: This is easy to understand and easy to use

Comment: i want to add the sections in this but i am not able to get from where it is happening ,i want to add diffrent layouts in each section but i am not able to get that

Comment: where to add layouts??

Comment: in each section i have to show diffrent layouts that will have edit text btns .

Comment: OK, can you send me `Layout.xml` file with description where/what to add  I'll try that for you. if??

Comment: yet i don't have any specific Layout.xml you can say that for first i have to edit text and a button in tha layout .how we can add more sections in this ??

Comment: Sorry for that but Please make some `Layout.xml`, first if you are not getting correct results then tell m, I will try to set that..

Comment: How can i get a click event on a section header. Any help

Comment: Please see referenced github link above, try it out and make sure you get the job done if not yet then ask a new  question!

Answer (score 2):

You can start with ExpandableListView and customize it to your need. I think this would be a good way to start. Please follow a link below to customize ExpandableListView :

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

You can google for more links on customizing expandablelistview. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scaleAnimation where you can add in each section a layout panel and inside the layout textview or anything as your requirement. See this. Hope it might help you.

http://wwwpriyaandroid.blogspot.in/2013/10/accordion.html